# while running command sudo yum update -y give dependency error

Tags: centos7

```
Error: Package: memcached-1.5.10-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi) Requires: libsasl2.so.2()(64bit)
```

i am trying to update sudo yum update -y it give me above error please help me how to fix this error

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Missing base repository, this dependency is provided by cyrus-sasl-lib-2.1.23-15.el6_6.2.x86_64

Comment: yes i already did and installed that library but error still persists

Comment: rpm -qa 'cyrus*'